# Change style of date to British style using chicago

Tags: chicago-style, biblatex-chicago, date

I am using British English throughout my document. However, biblatex-chicago uses American style Dates e.g. "February 3, 2016". I would like to change it to British style: "3rd February, 2016". How can I do this?

(this is a requirement by the examiner of the work)

Comment: Can you show us an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) of what you have so far? Do you use `babel`? If so with which language setting (`english`, `american`, or `british`)? What have you tried so far to get the right format?

Comment: Any news here? The answer will depend on your language settings, so we need to know what you are doing and if you are using `babel`/`polyglossia`  at all.